# Lost or stolen Passport when applying for Russian Visa

Tags: visas, passports, russia

There is a question on the [Russian Visa Application Form](https://visa.kdmid.ru/) that asks:

> Has your passport ever been lost or stolen?

My girlfriend submitted a lost passport report with the US government but later found the passport. Should she answer yes or no to this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes.

She lost a passport and reported it lost. At that point the government invalidated it and it can no longer be used for travel, even if she found it again.

**Do not attempt to use the passport that was reported lost to apply for a visa or travel.** You must replace the passport.

Comment: Thanks. She did replace the passport and is using that for the visa and travel. We were just wondering about the question on the form.